# Conditional Probability and Independence of Events

Tags: probability, independence

The unemployment rate for teens (ages 16-19)is 14.7% and for adults 20 and older it is 4.2%.We assume that 7% of the workforce are teenagers. What is the probability that a person randomly selected from this workforce population is age 20 and older and unemployed?

I know that the equation to use is P(20+ and unemployed)= P(B) P(A/B) but I am not sure how to solve because I thought the problem already says that the unemployment rate for people 20 and older is 4.2%.

Thank you!

Comment: The unemployment rate for people 20 and older is 4.2%, but 4.2% is not the percent of the workforce that is 20 and older and unemployed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am thinking...

Let $P(T)$ be the probability you're a teenager that works. 
Therefore $P(T)=0.07$, and the probability that you're are not a teenager that works is,
$P(T') = 1 - P(T) = 0.93$.

Let $u$ be the event that you're unemployed. We are given $P(u\mid T) = 0.147$ and $P(u\mid T') = 0.042$.

As you said, $P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A\mid B)P(B)$ and the question asks $P(\text{you're 20+ and unemployed})$.  So $P(T' \text{ and } u)$ is given by either $P(T'\mid u)P(u)$ or $P(u\mid T')P(T')$.

From the latter, $P(T' \text{ and } u) = P(u\mid T')P(T') = (0.042)(0.93)$